# How to implement a hierarchical structure of several nested composite types in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql

I am trying to implement a database in PostgreSQL 11.7, which should represent a hierarchical structure of several nested composite types. Currently I have the following defined (simplified):

```
CREATE TYPE type_school as (code integer, descr text); 
CREATE TYPE type_district as (code integer, descr text, schools type_school[]);
CREATE TYPE type_city as (code integer, descr text, districts type_district[]);
CREATE TYPE type_country as (code integer, descr text, cities type_city[]);
```

and a single table:

```
CREATE TABLE countries (country type_country);
```

For example these should be valid records (the descr column is optional and not of interest):

country with code 1, cities 3,4,5 with districts {1,2}, {1,3}, {3,6}
country with code 2, cities 3,6  with districts {3,7}, {7,9}

To populate the table I use INSERT for the country and UPDATE for the other elements:

```
INSERT INTO countries values(ROW(1, 'country descr', ARRAY[]::type_city[]));
UPDATE countries SET(country.city[1].code, country.city[1].descr) = (1, 'city descr') WHERE (country).code = 1;
UPDATE countries SET(country.city[1].district[2].code, country.city[1].district[2].descr) = (2, 'district descr') WHERE (country).code = 1;
```

This setup works alright, as I can perform most of the necessary queries. However I do not think this is the correct approach. I am a C programmer with no experience in database programming. I view this arrangement as a array of `struct` elements, consisting of more arrays of `struct`. And I am used to accessing the elements by indexing, which is what you see in this implementation. I would like to have some of the features of the database, such as constraints. These however are not possible on PostgreSQL types, only on tables. And if I define the array as a table, I do not know how to write the `INSERT` queries to access an inner table. According to some websites, nested tables are not possible in PostgreSQL, they recommend using arrays. Is it possible to enforce constraints in an array of composite type? Another suggestion I found on the web is using the `ltree` extension. However it seems to me that the tree elements are all of the same type and I have a different type on each level. Also in my current implementation I do not know how to delete a certain element and all of its sub-elements. So my question is:

How should one implement a table to represent a tree-like structure, consisting of 4 levels, each level representing a different type, so that constraints can be specified for the elements of each type? Is it even possible to do it with a relational database? And just to be clear, all I have to differentiate the elements is an index, and each elements is identified uniquely only by its path `country[i]->city[j]->district[k]->school[l]`.

Comment: No, this is all wrong. Normalize the database model: each column should hold only a single ("atomic") value. Put the data in different tables with foreign key relationships between them.

Comment: Does that mean that the bottom table (schools) should have 3 foreign keys  - country, city and district, and a district will have 2 for country and city?

Comment: `school` will have a foreign key to `district`, `district` will have a foreign key to `city` and `city` will have a foreign key to `country`. To select data, you join the tables; that is very efficient.

Comment: Alright, but since I can have duplicate city or district codes in different countries and cities, how do I create the foreign key? If the primary key of city is (country_code, city_code) I can have country 1 with cities 1,2 and country 2 with cities 1,2. But how do I reference this combination as a foreign key in district?

Comment: Then the foreign key will have to reference both of them. Often people use artificially generated numeric primary keys to avoid that, but it is no problem to have a primary key consisting of two columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Laurenz Albe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6464308/laurenz-albe) for pointing me in the right direction. I am posting a solution with code, in case anybody else needs a working example.

First create the top level table:

```
CREATE TABLE countries(code INTEGER, descr TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(code));
```

The table on the next level uses its code and the code from the top level table as its primary key. This way duplicate values for its column 'code' are possible, as the combination of code_country and code_city must be unique:

```
CREATE TABLE cities(code INTEGER, 
descr TEXT, 
code_country INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(code_country) REFERENCES countries(code),
PRIMARY KEY(code_country, code));
```

The table on the third level should use the primary key of its parent as a foreign key. This is accomplished by omitting the column names in the `REFERENCES` directive:

```
CREATE TABLE district(code INTEGER, 
descr TEXT,
code_country INTEGER,
code_city INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(code_country, code_city) REFERENCES cities,
PRIMARY KEY(code_country, code_city, code));
```

Adding constraints is now trivial.